# Конкатенация изображений в <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, css

нужно сделать приложение для конкатенации изображений,которые берутся из 2 инпутов(в разметке должны быть только 2 инпута и канвас)
и отображаются в теге canvas.На данный момент получается отображать только 1 инпут,и не понимаю как сделать для обоих картинок

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploaded-file');
let uploadedFile2 = document.getElementById('uploaded-file2');


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initImageLoader);



function initImageLoader(){
     uploadedFile.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);
    uploadedFile2.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);

        function handleManualUploadedFiles (ev){
            let file = ev.target.files[0];
            let file2 = ev.target.files[1];
            handleFile(file,file2);
        }
}

function handleFile (file,file2){
    let imageType = /image.*/;

    if(file.type.match(imageType) ){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            let tempImageStore =new Image();
            tempImageStore.onload = function(ev) {
                canvas.height = ev.target.height;
                canvas.width = ev.target.width;

                context.drawImage(ev.target,0,0);
            }
            tempImageStore.src = event.target.result; 
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в принципе все правильно, только не надо менять размер канвы под размер вновь загруженной картинки и рисование я применяю со смещением чтобы было видно оба изображения, а Вы рисуете одно поверх другого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploaded-file');
let uploadedFile2 = document.getElementById('uploaded-file2');


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initImageLoader);



function initImageLoader(){
     uploadedFile.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);
    uploadedFile2.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);

        function handleManualUploadedFiles (ev){
            let file = ev.target.files[0];
            handleFile(this, file);
        }
}

function handleFile (input, file){
    let imageType = /image.*/;

    if(file.type.match(imageType) ){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            let tempImageStore =new Image();
            tempImageStore.onload = function(ev) {
                context.drawImage(ev.target,input.id==="uploaded-file2"?100:0,0);
            }
            tempImageStore.src = event.target.result; 
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploaded-file">
<input type="file" id="uploaded-file2"><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

PS: Еще Вы как-то странно пытаетесь брать значения из обоих инпутов одновременно, функция `handleManualUploadedFiles` срабатывает по разу для каждого инпута и обрабатывает файл или файлы выбранные в одном инпуте