# как правильно реализовать функционал в приложении по сложению изображений

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пишу приложение по конкатенации изображений,и один из пунктов "Изображения должны отображаться в масштабе, поэтому две картины будут иметь одинаковую высоту на холсте, но с исходным соотношением сторон." И я не понимаю как это должно отображаться,может кто-то объяснит мне тормозу... ниже код работающей версии

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploaded-file');
let uploadedFile2 = document.getElementById('uploaded-file2');


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initImageLoader);



function initImageLoader(){
     uploadedFile.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);
    uploadedFile2.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles);

        function handleManualUploadedFiles (ev){
            let file = ev.target.files[0];
            handleFile(this, file);
        }
}

function handleFile (input, file){
    let imageType = /image.*/;

    if(file.type.match(imageType) ){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            let tempImageStore =new Image();
            tempImageStore.onload = function(ev) {
                context.drawImage(ev.target,input.id==="uploaded-file2"?0:0,0); //наверняка нужно изменить проверку тут,но пока я не понимаю что именно надо делать
            }
            tempImageStore.src = event.target.result; 
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: я понял следующее: есть канва и 2 картинки, все они разных размеров, картинки необходимо подогнать по высоте к высоте канвы, при этом сохранив их пропорции и нарисовать их, вот только не понятно одну да одной со смещением или одну поверх другой

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конкатенация изображений в <canvas>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984500/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-canvas)